# Contacts being added automatically

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, contacts, exchange

Somehow, contacts are being added automatically to my Mac address book.  They contain only an email address, which suggests that a mail program is creating these entries automatically.  The only email clients I use are Mac Mail on the desktop and the Mail app on iPhone.  I can't find any setting in either app that would cause this behavior.

New entries are even being created for email addresses that are already associated with an existing contact.  And if I delete them, they just come back again (though I can't tell when exactly that happens).

Mac Mail is set up for an iCloud account and an Exchange account.  But the entries that are being added do not exist in the Exchange directory.

From Mac Mail, I tested both sending and receiving to/from an address not in my address book, but I did not observe an entry being created automatically.

Any idea what else might be causing this behavior?!

Comment: are all emails from same origin. i.e gmail?

Comment: I've gotta think Exchange is to blame here. On the desktop it (well, Outlook) will create "suggested" contacts when you email someone, and I'm wondering if somehow those are being created in the Address Book. If you look at Contacts.app on your Mac, on the left-hand side you should be able to select the Exchange account and it will show only those contacts which exist within that account. Does that show these mystery contacts?

Comment: Outlook has it's own addressbook sync that would shove them straight into your addressbook, not on the Exchange side...

Comment: @Alex, I don't use Outlook at all (it's installed, but I only use the Mac Mail.app)

Comment: @tubedogg, oddly these auto-added contacts only show up under "All Contacts" - not under "Exchange", "On My Mac", or any other section